# javascript and css firefox issue

Tags: javascript, css, css-float

The popup perfectly works in chrome but its not working in firefox 
i have gave css: `float:left;` but its not getting fixed

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/s6hBG/21/

CSS:

```
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}


.openme {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #333;
    padding: 10px;
}

#menu{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px;
    background: -webkit-canvas(menu_background) no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}

#menu a{
    float:left;
    margin: 7px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 50%, 0% 51%, from(#fff), to(#edeff3));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #edeff3);
}

.hide { 
    opacity: 0; 
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;  
}​
```

Comment: Imo problem is in canvas element adding into firefox into #menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Chrome displays the canvas as a background of `div#menu`.  In Firefox, a `canvas` element is actually created.  Because the canvas element is displayed as a `block`, it appears below the `a` elements that precede it.

Comment: thanks for ur reply http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/s6hBG/21/ can u edit it in jsfiddle because i am not getting it

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#moz_background
{
    display:none;
}
```

And change this:

```
#menu{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px;
    background: -webkit-canvas(menu_background) ;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}
```

to:

```
#menu
{
    position:absolute;
    padding:20px 0px 0px;
    background:-webkit-canvas(menu_background) no-repeat;
    background:-moz-element(#moz_background) no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 300ms ease-out;
    -moz-transition:opacity 300ms ease-out;
    transition:opacity 300ms ease-out;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s6hBG/22/)**

Comment: @snuffin: thanks for your reply i am facin i wanted to display the pop up above when we click this link <a class="openme">Find ATM Locations</a> i changed the html structure but its not working...pls help me

Comment: @snuffin: i did not solve the problem how to make the popup come above the find atm link....i am dealing with another problem now

Comment: @snuffin i wanted the arrow pointing towards this link <a class="openme">Find ATM Locations</a>  http://jsfiddle.net/rajkumart08/s6hBG/45/

Comment: @snuffin: i am talking about the arrow...i didnot get the anwser help me out